# abstracting class instantiation

Tags: c#, generics, constructor

I have a base abstract class with several classes which extend and override it, however they all have the same constructor.  Right now I call each constructor from a switch statement:

```
case 1: return new A(arg1); // arg is int
```

etc., for about 10 classes. Is there a way with generics or delegates to make one method which would take a classname and instantiate that type with the arguments?

This would help, since if I make a change to the constructors I also have to change each instantiation.

A delegate would be most straight-forward but research says no to assigning constructors to delegates.

ADDITION:
I am now on wifi with my laptop and not just my cell, so here comes some code.

This is an example of what happens now:

```
switch (new Random().Next(4))
{
    case 3:
         // classA : baseClass, args{int, bool, otherClass}
         return new classA(arg1, arg2, arg3);
    case 2:
         // classB : baseClass, args{int, bool, otherClass}
         return new classB(arg1, arg2, arg3);
    case 1:
         // classC : baseClass, args{int, bool, otherClass}
         return new classC(arg1, arg2, arg3);
    case 0:
         // classD : baseClass, args{int, bool, otherClass}
         return new classD(arg1, arg2, arg3);
    default:
         continue;
}
```

I would like to call one instantiator at the end of the block with the three arguments.

A solution I thought of is to make and instantiator class that works similar to this:

```
ClassInstantiator inst = new ClassInstantiator(arg1, arg2, arg3);
switch(new Random().Next(4))
{
     case 4:
         return inst.instantiate<classA>();
     ...
}
```

Is this already built in to the language, or does anyone know of a more elegant solution?

Comment: +1 for a great question.

Comment: I realize after further thinking that the Activator is the technique I partially described above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only constructor-related constraint you can put on a generic type is the `new()` constraint, which requires a public parameterless constructor.

You could use reflection; the example assumes that all the related types have a constructor taking an int, as in your example, and that the abstract base class is called `B`:

```
public T CreateInstance<T>(int i) where T : B
{
    return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), i);
}
```

Then you'd call it like this:

```
A a = CreateInstance<A>(3);
```

Comment: Also, note that if you actually use the `new()` constraint, you get a compiler-generated call to `Activator.CreateInstance` whenever you say `new`.

Answer (score 5):

You can't get away from the fact that something has to decide on a conditional basis what to construct, but you can encapsulate it.  May I present to you one of the most popular GOF patterns: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern

e.g.

```
public abstract class MyBase(string name){}
public class Concrete1 : MyBase{}
public class Concrete2 : MyBase{}

public class MyFactory
{
   public MyBase Create(Criteria criteria)
   {
       //conditional logic/reflection
   }
}
```

Comment: So basically you have another class for each class you want to instantiate?... problem is this doesn't get me away from calling with the same arguments for each case statement. I would, for example, like to store the classname A in a variable then call a method using the variable to instantiate the desired class with the common arguments.

Comment: No, you have a single class that encapsulates the selection of the concrete type inside a single method that returns the base type.  This requires you to pass something as a criteria for the selection.  You mentioned the type, you could use that (in which case reflection may be ideal @phoog), or there might be another more domain specific criteria?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a dictionary with the class name as key and a constructor delegate as value.

```
Dictionary<string,Func<int,BaseClass>> _dict = new Dictionary<string,Func<int,BaseClass>>();
_dict.Add("ClassA", i => new ClassA(i));
_dict.Add("ClassB", i => new ClassB(i));

// Create ClassA object by class name
BaseClass obj = _dict["ClassA"](5);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't mean to over-complicate your problem, but if you find that you have a lot of this kind of code, then you might be interested in using an IoC Container.

Popular IoC Containers:

- [StructureMap](http://structuremap.net/structuremap/)
- [Spring.NET](http://www.springframework.net/)
- [Unity / Enterprise Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648512.aspx)
- Castle Windsor
- [Ninject](http://ninject.org/)
- [Others](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ListOfNETDependencyInjectionContainersIOC.aspx)

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with you, but can you explain further? Is it the case that these containers can instantiate different concretes dependent on constructor arg type?

Comment: @MylesMcDonnell as I understand the question, the logic is conditional on something other than the constructor arg type (I presume that "they all have the same constructor" means that the constructors all have the same number of parameters with the same type).

Comment: Yes, you are right, my comment above was nonsense in the context of this question.  Although I would be interested to know if there are any containers that could select a concrete implmentation acording to the concrete type of an arg? I expect there are and I expect generics are the enabling factor.

Comment: @Myles - I believe so. It looks like [StructureMap supports configuring conditional instances](http://structuremap.net/structuremap/InstanceExpression.htm#section18), but I haven't used that feature.
I apologize for providing such a vague answer to the question. I usually like to provide some examples but am just not able to at the moment. I posted it as a community wiki, thinking that perhaps someone else will want to add some details to this answer.